# inventory system

Tags: database-design

I am trying to develop an **online inventory system**.
I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `ProductId` 
  `SubCategoryTypeId` 
  `MerchantId` 
  `ProductName`
  `MRP` 
  `Quantity` 
  `ProductCode` 
  `ProductSKUCode` 
  `BarCode`
  `Description_short`
  `Description_long`
  `ThumbnailImage`
  `ProductImage`
  `OurPrice`
  `MinBargainPrice`
  `Brand`
  `AirCost`
  `SurfaceCost`
  `ShippingAirTime`
  `ShippingSurfaceTime`
  `ColorCode`
  `DiscountPercent`
  `IsApproved`
  `IsActive`
  `HasSize`
  `isOnlineProduct`
  `isOfflineProduct`
  `ShippingCategory`
  `ProductExpiryDays`
  `RelatedVideo`
  `TechnicalSpecification`
  `CreatedDateTime`
  `ModifiedDateTime`
  `CreatedBy`
  `ModifiedBy`
  `IsCod`
  `HasOffer`
  `OfferText`
  `IsNewArrival`
  `HasColor`
  `NoOfRecommendation`
  `IsPremium` tinyint(1) 
  `IsImported`
  PRIMARY KEY (`ProductId`),
  KEY `Product_Category_Rel` (`SubCategoryTypeId`),
  KEY `Product_Merchant_Rel` (`MerchantId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2093 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='This table contains Product data.';
```

Using this table I can add most of the products but how I can optimize this table so that books can also be added. I am having problem in adding books since it has author, publisher etc. Can any one suggest what to do so that I can add books also?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can try to split your table in more table with normalization rules. Try to understand how relationship can be apply. For example, your table from database can be split in a table with names of product ant other table can be used to insert product properties as IsNewArrival.

Comment: How i will detect the product is book since for other product the system works fine.If the product is book the ui will contain publisher, author etc.

Comment: The book is just an example of product.

Answer (score 0):

I use Generalization/Specialization. For Example you have a table for products with all commun data in it... but have others table for more expecifics data (like your books).
A better example, suppoust that you sell Books, Movies and other things like pens, pencils, print papper, etc (library things). Well you can have a table of products with ProductID(pk), name (varchar), description (varchar). Also you can have Books table with BookID (pk), AuthorID(FK to Author table), ISBN (varchar), EditorialID(FK to Editorial table)... but also you set BookID FK to Products.ProductID so, when you insert a book in books table first insert a Product in Products table, that ID is the Books.bookID... (same thing to movies table)

Hope to understand me.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I understood what you have said and am going to do the same but the the problem is, while displaying am fetching from product table and display the data like product name, barcode, size if available etc.etc. When the product is like books or movies then the product display will be different.I have to check specifically that the product is book or movie and display the product. If there are similar multiple product like movie or book then i have to put multiple conditions.So what should be my approach?

Comment: One tool maybe will be use an aditional table ProductType and used to filter products by types... and for display all your products could use views, setting to empty those fields that dont be on Product Table. (Sorry by my english by the way) Hope to understand me.